# How is the barrel shifter implemented in modern ARM/ARM64 CPUs?

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture, arm64

ARM has a barrel shifter that can be used to shift the 2nd operand of an instruction. One can thus write

```
add    x0, x0, x1, lsl #2
```

instead of

```
lsl    x1, x1, #2
add    x0, x0, x1
```

I found some documentation for old ARM CPUs (like [this ARM2 page on wikichip](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/acorn/microarchitectures/arm2)), which seems to show that the 2nd operand of an instruction used to go through the barrel shifter before reaching the ALU.

However, I couldn't find the same information on more recent CPUs. For instance, the [Wikichip page of the Cortex-A76](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/arm_holdings/microarchitectures/cortex-a76) doesn't mention the barrel shifter at all, and the [diagram of the core](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/File:cortex-a76_block_diagram.svg) doesn't show a dedicated barrel shifter unit.

**Is there still a dedicated barrel shifter unit on modern ARM/ARM64 CPUs, or do they use regular ALU units instead?**
(I'm interested in both ARM and ARM64, but if the answer has to be CPU-specific, let's say Cortex-A76)

I'm asking this question because I'm wondering if/when it makes sense to use the barrel shifter for repeated computations or not. For instance, consider this function:

```
int f(int* arr1, long int offset, int repl) {
  int a = arr1[offset];
  arr1[offset] = repl;
  return a;
}
```

Should it be implemented in assembly with

```
ldr     w3, [x0, x1, lsl #2]
str     w2, [x0, x1, lsl #2]
```

or with

```
lsl     x1, x1, #2
ldr     w3, [x0, x1]
str     w2, [x0, x1]
```

GCC 13.2 [seems to prefer the former](https://godbolt.org/z/j44Meb9Mn), but GCC 14.0 Trunk [prefers to latter](https://godbolt.org/z/bajbd95Ea).
I'm guessing that the exact implementation of the barrel shifter will impact which one is faster. (let's assume for this question that register pressure is not an issue)

Comment: You didn't use a `-mtune=` or `-mcpu=` for either of your builds, and "generic" tuning settings do get updated between releases to try to keep up with actual CPUs.  For software-relevant performance tuning info, check the optimization manuals for some specific cores like A53 (in-order) and A77 (out-of-order) to see what they say about latency and which execution "pipes" an instruction can run on.

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) Good point about -mtune. So, for A53, GCC generates the version with the shifted offset, for for A77, the shift is computed before. Regarding the optimization manuals, it's interesting but surprising: for A77, "Load register, register offset, basic" (which, if I'm not mistaken, is what my example is using) only uses the L pipeline and always has latency 4 and throughput 2. However, if that's indeed correct, I don't see why GCC would choose to compute the shift first (which would add a 1 cycle latency). What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing that GCC is often imperfect.  It's a complex piece of machinery that manages to generate good-enough code most of the time. It uses sub-optimal addressing modes all the time when tuning for Intel x86-64 CPUs.  (I'm not sure it or clang are aware of [Micro fusion and addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26046634) especially when unrolling loops.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a direct answer in [gcc cost tables](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/arm/aarch-cost-tables.h;h=e384821472864ba26d085a24bd9c917d6b834baa;hb=HEAD#l346); that is to say for `add`,`sub`, ALU instruction when a signed register shift is used, there is a single cycle penalty for signed shifts only.  For load/store, there is no penalty.  This beneficial as compilers can convert indexes to addresses easily.

```
 add     r0, r1, r0, asr #2   ; one cycle.
 add     r0, r1, r0, lsr #2   ; no penalty.
 ldr     w3, [x0, x1, lsl #2] ; no penalty.
```

I would double check the technical reference manual for the core.  It is unlikely that the load/store forms (last example) would have a penalty as it would be bad for *LOTS* of compiled code.

---

Here is some information on a [barrel shifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter).  Note that ARMv2 was designed in 1980 and technology like Verilog and VHDL was just being invented.  At this time designer looked at every gate.  The 'barrel shifter' is a technology to perform a dynamic shift operation.  There are multiple ways to implement this.  A fixed shift in hardware is just wires from source to destination that perform the shift/rotate.

> Is there still a dedicated barrel shifter unit on modern ARM/ARM64 CPUs, or do they use regular ALU units instead?

While, I hardly know, I can not imagine a 'dedicated anything'?  In all likelihood, there is 'shift.v' or something like this.  You can make as many cookie cutters of 'shift.v' as you want after you have an initial design.  Tools will now re-implement/connect whatever the 'shift.v' module does.  So each load store unit may have a shifter and/or all the operands that support shifted registers.  There can also be multiple copies of a register, in a design.  In the 1980s people might sweat over a shifter.  CPUs took multiple cycles to complete everything. RAM was never a real problem (relating to speed).  Today, I would think that are probably 1000s of shifter circuits in a CPU and a CPU can wait 1000s of cycles for external RAM.

> Should it be implemented in assembly with

For,

1. Power
2. Code size
3. Execution speed

Item 2,3 are probably tied.  Unless the documentation for a CPU says this takes extra cycles (unlikely for Cortex-A designs or later), then replicating the shift is the best way to go.

It is entirely possible that the single shift could save power, but unlikely due to the large overhead inside a CPU that will get drained by the extra instruction fetches.

Even bigger than the shift cost at the compiler level is managing the data flow.  The compiler will do different things, depending on how important it judges things.  If you don't have this in a loop, so unrelated code section can lead to alternate instruction choices.  I think relying on a compiler is faulty (for this questions topic).  You need to consult the technical reference manual for the CPU of interest.

The general best practice is,

1. Choice code that reads the best.
2. Built a successful prototype.
3. Profile the system.
4. Only then optimize where it is needed.

Item four is often only answered when you have a complete embodiment, as many system devices (cache, RAM, CPU) interact to impact performance.  Also premature optimization can limit the code when/if it moves to another platform.  Most commonly, modern CPUs wait around for RAM and items like a specific opcode type are rarely where performance gains can be found; as oppose to technology shift like using SIMD, fixed point/integer, etc.

Comment: For an Cortex-A76, it is super-scaler and this (multiple shifts) might actually matter.  It just seems unreasonable that it would have a material affect beyond all the other other concerns to keep a CPU feed with data.

Comment: *You can make as many cookie cutters of 'shift.v' as you want* - That's what they mean by "dedicated" - not a special design, but another instance of it separate from the main ALU (in each integer pipe).  I think they're considering the possibility that an ADD instruction with a shifted source might occupy the ALU for 2 cycles, one for the shift and the other for the addition.  But with an extra instance of a barrel shifter on the input path to the ALU, only critical path latency is worse, not throughput.  (And depending on clock speed, a single cycle could be long enough for both.)

Comment: Re: your last paragraph: compilers have options like `-mtune=some_specific_cpu` for a reason.  It would be good (if it didn't bloat the compiler internals too much) if they could make optimal decisions for stuff like this, using shorter sequences when not slower.  So **compiler developers** *should* care about this, and people inspecting the asm output should file missed-optimization bug reports (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/ / https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) after looking for duplicates.  Trying to micro-optimize every part of a large C program separately is folly, though.

Comment: [The cost tables](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/arm/aarch-cost-tables.h;h=e384821472864ba26d085a24bd9c917d6b834baa;hb=HEAD#l346) have the information and they have 1 cycle for arithmetic shifts (for add,sub,eor, etc); There is no penalty of ld/st addresses.  Also they are not **ALWAYS** barrel shifters.  The shifter can be made with a hierarchy of multiplexers.  A barrel shifter is a single big multiplexer.  Also, you do not need to pipeline anything if you can prove all PVT (chip operating parameters) will meet timing for a single ALU path.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of detail that could go into your answer to more directly address what I think the OP was trying to ask, maybe instead of some of the first part of your paragraph about not understanding what they mean by a "dedicated" shifter, if you agree with my reading of what they're probably asking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The gcc cost tables are indeed useful. I don't have time right now, but I'll have a look at the commit that introduced the costs for A76 to see if it mentions where these costs came from. Thanks also for the discussion on CPU design; useful as well :)

Comment: And thanks @PeterCordes for the comments, your interpretation of my question is correct. I was indeed asking in the context of developing a compiler, and was wondering if it's better to duplicate shifted operands or not (where "better" is mostly judged by the execution speed of the generated code).

Answer (score 2):

ARM publishes a Software Optimization Guide for each of its cores, with latency and throughput cycle counts and pipeline utilization.  [Here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/pjdoc466751330-7215/latest/) is the one for Cortex A-76.

(Pay attention when reading that each section has separate tables for AArch64 and AArch32, which are only indicated by the column headers.  Also note that the guide only lists "real" instructions and not aliases, so you may have to refer to the Architecture Reference Manual to translate aliases.  For instance, there is no entry in the table for `mov xn, xm` because it is an alias of `orr xn, xzr, xm`, so you would look at `orr` instead.)

See page 14 for load instructions.  The entries for "Load register, register offset,
basic" and "Load register, register offset, scale by 4/8" both have 4 cycles latency (assuming L1 cache hit), and throughput of 2 per cycle.  This matches with the L under pipeline utilization, showing that they can run on either of the two load/store pipelines.

So in your case, `lsl #2` or `lsl #3` in a load instruction carries no penalty.

However, on the following line, `lsl #1` in a `ldrh/ldrsh` 16-bit load instruction does carry a penalty of one cycle of latency, and uses an I pipeline.  So we see that 2- and 3-bit shifters are integrated into the load-store unit, but a 1-bit shift has to use the ALU from one of the three integer pipelines.

On a similar note, checking page 9, an instruction like `add x0, x1, x2, lsl #n` has no penalty for `n <= 4` and can run on any of the three integer pipelines in 1 cycle, for max throughput of 3 per cycle.  But if `n > 4`, or if we use a right shift or rotate, then there is an extra cycle of latency, and it can only run on the M multi-cycle integer pipeline, so throughput is just 1 per cycle.

On the other hand, logic instructions can handle arbitrary shifts on any pipeline without penalty, so `and x0, x1, x2, lsl #17` is the same cost as `and x0, x1, x2`.  The exception is the flag-setting `ands/bics` which do have to go to the M pipeline, and cost an extra cycle of latency, if they include a shift.